# How do I get the ID of my dynamically created input and div in C# code behind

Tags: javascript, c#

I am dynamically creating input using JavaScript

```
<div  class="category" id="catgdiv" runat="server">
  <%= model.get(\'category\') %>:</div>\n<% } %>
    <div class="search_input_container">\n  
      <input id="srchinput" runat="server" type="text" 
             class="search_input ui-menu VS-interface" 
             value="" <% if (readOnly) { %>disabled="disabled"<% } %> />\n
    </div>
```

Now I want to use ID value on Button click event to pass the value using session Like:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session["place"]=srchinput.InnerText;
       // Session["place"] = text.Text;
        //Session["add"] = pnk.Value;
        Response.Redirect("searcch.aspx");

    }
```

Comment: searcch = search??? May save you some time later? :)

Comment: You have no client side code in your post. If you literally add the top item using javascript it will not do anything usefull, you can't add server side markup in the browser.

Comment: there is no javascript here... what do you think you are adding dynamically?

Comment: <div id="search_query2">&nbsp;</div>
<script src="salon.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
   </div> in client side i am creating dynamically ,so i am confused dow we use id of input and div

Comment: You should properly format (indent!) your HTML markup before posting it. What I'm seeing with this question is that you didn't put in a lot of effort up front, you're waiting on people to ask you for more details that you know (or should have known) should have been included with the question from the beginning.

Comment: ok from your comment I gather the part you want to get the ID from is in a .js file you did not even show us.  How do you expect us to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking in your question but you def. have some bugs and it is to long to put in a comment:

```
value="" <% if (readOnly) { %>disabled="disabled"<% } %> />
```

should be

```
value="<% if (readOnly) { %>disabled='disabled'<% } %>" />
```

Note the location of the quotes.

Comment: thnkx... actually using js input control is created ... so now how to use id of input in server side

Comment: I believe this is the same question as you are asking above.  Why do you think I would be able to answer it now?

Comment: @Hogan Wouldn't that output `value="disabled='disabled'" />` I think the original code was right.

Comment: it would output `value="disabled='disabled'"` which is the intention of the code -- correct or not is a different question.  We have no clue what this user is trying to do.